# How to copy the file description when forking instead of sharing?

Tags: linux, unix, posix, fork, file-descriptor

When a process forks, the child will share with its parent the file description that was open before the forking.

Is there a way to make the child have its own copy of the file description (that includes the offset and the file status flag)?

I need that since I don't want both parent and child to share the same offset of the file; if one process has done a read, I don't want the offset of the file for the second process to be changed.

Comment: Are you sure the file descriptor isn't duplicated?

Comment: the file descriptor is duplicated for the child but it points to the same open file entry I'm calling it here "file description" which inlcudes the offset and the status falg of the file. I need this to be duplicated as well.

Comment: This is something I'm interested in as well. Perhaps there are some non-portable ways of duplicating the in-kernel file description tables when forking?

Answer (score 0):

There's both an 'open file descriptor' and an 'open file description'.  When a file is opened with [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), both a file descriptor and a file description are created.  When a file descriptor is duplicated ([`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) or [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)), the two descriptors refer to the same open file description.

On [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html), the file descriptors in the parent are copied (duplicated) in the child; the descriptor in the parent and the child both point to the same open file description.

> *The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's file descriptors. Each of the child's file descriptors shall refer to the same open file description with the corresponding file descriptor of the parent.*

There's no way to have it work otherwise — you'd have to close and reopen the file to get a separate open file description.